# Let Linux recognize the AMD GPU, not the Intel GPU

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, gpu, amd-radeon

I'm trying to use the AMD Radeon R5 M435 GPU (a notebook GPU) with Fedora 32. It seems the GPU is not correctly detected.

I've reinstalled Fedora a few moments ago, in order to have a clean environment. I've updated the PCI database with the command `update-pciids`.
When I execute:

```
lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D|2D"
```

I get the output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

so it seems that the GPU is not present. But when I execute:

```
lspci -v
```

I get the output:

```
[...]
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230 / R7 M260DX / Radeon 520 Mobile] (rev c3)
  Subsystem: Dell Device 0844
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
  Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
  Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
  I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
  Expansion ROM at d0040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
  Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
  Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
  Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
  Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
  Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
  Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
  Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
  Kernel driver in use: radeon
  Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
[...]
```

This tells us that the GPU is present.

My question is if this GPU is supported by the Linux kernel, and, if so, how can I make it to be detected by Linux, so that the GPU appears in the output of `lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D|2D"`.

With regard to the driver installation, based on my research, AMDGPU drivers are installed by default in Linux, so I don't have to install drivers. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* detected by Linux. You're grepping for the wrong thing. (Think about why `lspci` shows the device but `lspci | grep` does not...)

On a laptop, the *only* device with "VGA compatible controller" will be the one that has the physical video outputs, the one that the firmware and everything will use when only the bare minimum "VGA" drivers are present. (Only the main GPU will be directly attached to outputs – the secondary GPU only processes the rendering commands but has to transfer the final image through the primary GPU.)

If you want a specific app to use the secondary GPU for 3D graphics, run it with the DRI_PRIME environment variable set, e.g. `DRI_PRIME=1 vim`.

Compare, for example:

- `glxinfo -B` (shows Intel GPU information)
- `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo -B` (shows AMD GPU information)

(Note: This applies to Mesa OpenGL. Vulkan has a different device selection method, although Mesa recently added a Vulkan layer that makes it honor DRI_PRIME or something like that.)

Comment: Thank you very much! It was an insightful answer.